# Finding area between two parallel lines

Tags: geometry, analytic-geometry

How can I compute the area between two parallel lines $y=5x+0.21$ and $y=5x+0.01$ inside a unit square, i.e. $0\leq x,y\leq1$?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**HINT**

- make a plot of the square and the lines
- find the intersection points $(0,0.21),(0,0.01)$,etc.
- note that we can obtain the area by subtracting the areas of two triangles

Answer (score 2):

By finding the integral:$$\int_0^1\int_0^1[5x+0.01\leq y\leq 5x+0.21]dydx$$where $[P(x,y)]$ denotes the function taking value $1$ if $P(x,y)$ is true and taking value $0$ otherwise.

But it is more handsome to choose for plotting as **gimusi** suggests.

Comment: The system of equations the OP has mentioned are *linear*, so I don't find it very likely that the OP has learnt about integration yet.

Answer (score 2):

Find the area of the two triangles, and the large rectangle

[image]

Comment: That's exactly the plot!